# vlookup - only return cell with text

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I need to return a cell that has text in it, but am running into difficulty.

[image]

Above is a sample table I'm working with. What I'd like to be able to do, is lookup id 1 and have it output Rich.  When I do a vlookup, however, it gives no output.  And while vlookup min/max will output integers, they don't work with text.  Does anyone know how I can scan multiple ids, but only output the filled text cell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be a shorter formula for this but I banged this off quickly and it does dynamically truncate the ranges in column B down to the minimum number of rows necessary.

```
=INDEX(B:B, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW(B2:INDEX(B:B, MATCH("zzz",B:B )))/(ISTEXT(B2:INDEX(B:B, MATCH("zzz",B:B )))*(A2:INDEX(A:A, MATCH("zzz",B:B )))=D3), 1))
```

[image: index_aggregate_rich]

To retrieve a second, third, etc. entry change the *k* parameter of AGGREGATE to a COUNTIF and fill down.

```
=INDEX(B:B, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW(B$2:INDEX(B:B, MATCH("zzz",B:B )))/(ISTEXT(B$2:INDEX(B:B, MATCH("zzz",B:B )))*(A$2:INDEX(A:A, MATCH("zzz",B:B )))=D3), COUNTIF(D$3:D3, D3)))
```

[image: index_aggregate_rich2]

Comment: If you could be dealing with zero-length strings, change the denominator to `(ISTEXT(B$2:INDEX(B:B, MATCH("zzz",B:B )))*SIGN(LEN(B$2:INDEX(B:B, MATCH("zzz",B:B ))))*(A$2:INDEX(A:A, MATCH("zzz",B:B ))=D3))`.

Comment: that worked!  thanks jeeped!  How in the heck did you figure this out?

Comment: The [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) has an option to ignore errors. All you have to do is supply a series of potential row numbers and divide any non-matching ones by zero. The denominator in that equation is just a series of booleans multiplied against each other. If any is false then the denominator is zero. Divide a row number by zero and you get `#DIV/0!` and aggregate ignores it.

Comment: I just learned today that you can also use Combine Row Wizard, which is an excel add in by AbleBits.  Your formula worked perfectly, but when you have a large (>100k rows) database, using the formula often caused excel to become unresponsive.  Combine Row Wizard is great solution for big datasets.